# Include non python files in RPM with setuptools

Tags: python, rpm, setuptools

I have some fixture directories that contain xml files that I would like included with my python project when building the RPM with `bdist_rpm`.  I thought I could do this by having MANIFEST.in do a `recursive-include * *`, however, it does not include anything other than *.py files.  Is there anyway to have bdist_rpm include non python files in the package or specifically include *.xml files as well?

Answer (score 3):

Where are you trying to install them?  If you put them inside a package directory, like this...

```
myproject/
  mypackage/
    __init__.py
    resources/
      file1.xml
      file2.xml
```

...you can use the `package_data` option in your `setup.py` file, like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
        name='myproject',
        version='0.1',
        description='A description.',
        packages=find_packages(),
        include_package_data=True,
        package_data = { '': [ '*.xml' ] },
        install_requires=[],
        )
```

This will recursively include any `*.xml` files inside of any packages.  They'll get installed with the rest of your package(s) somewhere inside of the Python library path.  You can do the same thing with a `MANIFEST.in` that looks like this:

```
recursive-include * *.xml
```

If you're trying to install them into specific filesystem locations outside of the Python library, I'm not sure if you can do that via `setup.py`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `data_files` parameter of setup to do what you need. Something like this:

```
setup(
    ...
    package_data = { '/usr/share/yourapp/xmls': [ 'xmls/1.xml', 'xmls/2.xml' ] },
    ...
)
```

This would install following files:

```
/usr/share/yourapp/xmls/1.xml
/usr/share/yourapp/xmls/2.xml
```

I generally create the list of files in a function like this:

```
def get_xmls():
    xmlfiles = []
    for filename in os.listdir('xmls/'):
        if filename.endswith('.xml'):
            xmlfiles.append('xmls/%s' % filename)
    return xmlfiles
```